# rsyslog not sending nova, neutron logs from openstack controller

Tags: rsyslog, openstack

I have my `rsyslog` server setup and I want to collect logs from my OpenStack controller. I have followed these steps, https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/OpsGuide-Logging-RSysLog but I am not able to see my `nova`, `neutron`, or `cinder` logs. I know my `rsyslog` server is working because I am able to see `horizon`, `swift` and `rabbitmq` logs getting added into my `rsyslog` server. If anyone can help me to debug this issue would be of great help.

Here are the contents of my rsyslog conf file:

- Server: `/etc/rsyslog.d/server.conf`

  ```
  module(load="imtcp")
  input(type="imtcp" port="514")

  $ModLoad imudp
  $UDPServerAddress 10.117.35.94
  $UDPServerRun 514

  $template NovaFile,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/nova.log"
  $template NovaAll,"/var/log/rsyslog/nova.log"


  $template DynFile,"/var/log/rsyslog/%HOSTNAME%/syslog.log"
  *.* ?DynFile

  local0.* ?NovaFile
  local0.* ?NovaAll
  & ~
  ```
- On my client or controller, `/etc/rsyslog.d/client.conf`

  ```
  *.* @10.117.35.94
  *.* @@10.117.35.94
  ```
- I have also set these in my `nova.conf` file.

  ```
  use_syslog = True
  syslog_log_facility = LOG_LOCAL0
  ```

I am using Openstack Mitaka version.